# how to preview an image before upload in various browsers

Tags: html, image, upload, preview

I want to show preview of an image before it is uploaded. I have found a partial solution that works for ie6 and firefox, and havent yet tested it in ie7 or ie8. But i want a solution that works in safari, ie7 and ie8 as well. Here is the solution obtained by combining the ie6 and firefox solution:

```
function preview(what) {
if(jQuery.browser.msie) {
document.getElementById("preview-photo").src=what.value;
return;
}
else if(jQuery.browser.safari) {
document.getElementById("preview-photo").src=what.value;
return;
}
document.getElementById("preview-photo").src=what.files[0].getAsDataURL();
//  alert(jQuery("#preview-photo").height());
//  alert(jQuery("#preview-photo").width());
var h = jQuery("#preview-photo").height();  
var w = jQuery("#preview-photo").width();//assuming width is 68, and height is floating
if ((h > 68) || (w > 68)){
if (h > w){
jQuery("#preview-photo").css("height", "68px");
jQuery("#preview-photo").css("width", "auto");
}else {
jQuery("#preview-photo").css("width", "68px");
jQuery("#preview-photo").css("height", "auto");
}
}
}
```

The getAsDataURL() part works in firefox, and the "src=what.value" part works in ie6, but what would work in safari, and does "src=what.value" work in ie7 and ie8 as well? If not, is there some solution that also works there? I will be happy if i can make the image preview work in 5 or 6 browsers. If it doesn't then is the only option to have two forms with image upload part of another form?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the following function. Tested on IE7+ and Firefox and chrome

```
function loadname(img, previewName){  

var isIE = (navigator.appName=="Microsoft Internet Explorer");  
var path = img.value;  
var ext = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf('.') + 1).toLowerCase();  

 if(ext == "gif" || ext == "jpeg" || ext == "jpg" ||  ext == "png" )  
 {       
    if(isIE) {  
       $('#'+ previewName).attr('src', path);  
    }else{  
       if (img.files[0]) 
        {  
            var reader = new FileReader();  
            reader.onload = function (e) {  
                $('#'+ previewName).attr('src', e.target.result);  
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(img.files[0]);  
        }  
    }  

 }else{  
  incorrect file type  
 }   
}  

<input type="file" name="image" onchange("loadname(this,'previewimg')") >
<img src="about:blank" name="previewimg" id="previewimg" alt="">
```

Answer (score 2):

Work in firefox and chrome

```
<input type="file" id="file" />
<div id="div"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function view() {
    var f = document.getElementById("file").files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (function(evt) {  //evt get all value
        document.getElementById('div').innerHTML = 
            "PIC :<img src=" +
            evt.target.result + "/>" ;
    });
    reader.readAsDataURL(f);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This will be a serious security issue if done. You can't have a preview of a file in the users computer. You have to upload the file to the server and can show the preview of the file after it is successfully uploaded.

Comment: Not true. The new HTML5 File API serves exactly this purpose. It fully protects the file path, and you have to read all data through a FileReader

Comment: Note this answer is 3 years old.

Answer (score 1):

Link to the [blob](http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/FileAPI/#blob) as you would link to any image, of course you have to update the src as soon as the images soon to be uploaded is given or changed, here is how I do it, I didn't have the time to test it in Windows Browsers (i.e IE).

This **example** also implements basic validation:
http://jsfiddle.net/J3GP7/

```
    <style>
        #image_preview {
            display:none;
        }
    </style>

    <form>
        <p>
            <label for="image">Image:</label><br />
            <input type="file" name="image" id="image" />
        </p>
    </form>
    <div id="image_preview">
        <img src="#" /><br />
        <a href="#">Remove</a>
    </div>

    <script>
    /** 
    onchange event handler for the file input field.
    * It emplements very basic validation using the file extension.
    * If the filename passes validation it will show the image 
    using it's blob URL and will hide the input field and show a delete
    button to allow the user to remove the image
    */
    jQuery('#image').on('change', function () {
        ext = jQuery(this).val().split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
        if (jQuery.inArray(ext, ['gif', 'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg']) == -1) {
            resetFormElement(jQuery(this));
            window.alert('Not an image!');
        } else {
            file = jQuery('#image').prop("files")[0];
            blobURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
            jQuery('#image_preview img').attr('src', blobURL);
            jQuery('#image_preview').slideDown();
            jQuery(this).slideUp();
        }
    });

    /**
    onclick event handler for the delete button.
    It removes the image, clears and unhides the file input field.
    */
    jQuery('#image_preview a').bind('click', function () {
        resetFormElement(jQuery('#image'));
        jQuery('#image').slideDown();
        jQuery(this).parent().slideUp();
        return false;
    });

    /** 
     * Reset form element
     * 
     * @param e jQuery object
     */
    function resetFormElement(e) {
        e.wrap('<form>').closest('form').get(0).reset();
        e.unwrap();
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

## jquery ajax file upload

```
$('[name="send"]').click(function(){

   view();

   v_data = {
                news_header : $('[name="news_header"]').val(),
                news_auth : $('[name="news_auth"]').val(),
                news_image : image, //this var taking for view() function what i use before
                news_news : $('[name="news_news"]').val()    

            };

   $("#show").html(v_data.news_Header + " " + v_data.news_auth + " "+ v_data.news_image + " "+ v_data.news_news );

   $.ajax({
        type    :   "POST",
        url     :   './insert_news_data.php',
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',        
        data    :   v_data,

        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
        }
   });


});
```